# Keyboard input with programmable keyboard

Tags: .net, keyboard

In my app I have programmable keyboard and I need to take input from my key that is pressed.
When I program keyboard keys for example one key is $65$, #a45a# ....
I have tried on `KeyPress` event, but only argument that I have is `e.KeyChar` which is char and take only one character from my input, for example when I press key with value $65$ `e.KeyChar` is only $.
Does anybody now how to solve this problem.

Thank you......

Comment: What is a '$65$' key (or '#a45a#')?

Comment: further to @PoweRoy do you want to capture multiple consecutive key presses, so is you user pressing '$' then '6' then '5' then '$' or does $65$ mean something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the `KeyUp` event? It receives more detailed key information.

Comment: Yes I have,but it doesn't work because on KeyUp i have e.KeyValue, e.KeyData ,e.KeyCode but neither of that work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Is this a macro key?

Comment: I have special keyboard on wich i program keyes for example on one key i set value $a$ when i press that key in text box i got that text on textbox.Now i have tree list and when i press one of that special keyes i will process to check right node.Only thing is that i can't get that value if it is not on some control.text or something similar.

Comment: can't you map it to 'normal' keystrokes. For example: Shift+Ctrl+Alt+A-Z. Maybe that works.

Comment: The keyboard is probably sending multiple keystrokes to the computer. You could capture several Key* events and take some action if there's a multikey match within some span of time. Sounds like an ideal application for Reactive Extensions.